# Pass ID of an element to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

I want to fetch the id of an element and pass it in jquery function -

```
              $('#fetchedID').fadeOut;
```

Till now I have tried -

```
1.  $("#$('.delete_status').attr('id')").fadeOut(400);

2.  var e = $('.delete_status').attr('id');
                 $(e).fadeOut(400);
```

I am sure I am stuck because of the wrong syntax of passing javascript variable in jQuery function. Please help.

Comment: Assuming this is running under an event handler, you can get the element using `this`, eg. `$(this).fadeOut();`. Assuming there is more than one element with the class `.delete_status` your code will only get the `id` from the first one it finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with **concating** the `Id` that you have got with the `Id selector(#)` like

```
var e = $('.delete_status').attr('id');
$("#" + e).fadeOut(400);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate the selector, like this:

```
$("#" + $('.delete_status').prop('id')).fadeOut(400);
```

If you're going to be using the ID more than once, it is a good idea to cache it:

```
var delete_status_id = $('.delete_status').prop('id');
$("#" + delete_status_id ).fadeOut(400);
// do something else with delete_status_id...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#" + $('.delete_status').attr('id')).fadeOut(400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to pick the ID to then reselect the element and do the fade? If you want to pick only the first occurence of your class, you can use `:eq(0)` instead.

```
$('.delete_status:eq(0)').fadeOut(400);
```